# Ionic app nested views not updating on Android

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am working on an Ionic application that has the following layout:

[image: Image of App Layout]

I have the following ui-router state setup for this section:

```js
$stateProvider

  .state('home', {
    name: 'home',
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/base.html"
  })
  .state('home.map', {
    url: "/main",
    cache: false,
    views: {
      'second': {
           templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
           controller: 'mapCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('home.list', {
    url: '/list',
    cache: false,
    views: {
      'second': {
           templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
           controller: 'listCtrl'
      }
    }  
  })
  
  .state('home.deals', {
    url: '/deals',
    cache: false,
    views: {
      'second': {
           templateUrl: 'templates/deals.html',
           controller: 'dealsCtrl'
      }
    }  
  })
```

This works great when switch states with the following controls in the header view via the web browser:

```html
<div class="col-33 mapPageColPadding">
    <button ui-sref="home.map" ng-class = "{active: isActive('/main'), mapPageBottomHeaderButtons: true}">MAP</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-33 mapPageColPadding">
    <button ui-sref="home.list" ng-class = "{active: isActive('/list'), mapPageBottomHeaderButtons: true}">LIST</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-33 mapPageColPadding">
    <button ui-sref="home.deals" ng-class = "{active: isActive('/deals'), mapPageBottomHeaderButtons: true}">DEALS</button>
</div>
```

Here is my base.html:

```html
   <ion-content scroll="true">
     <div ng-include src="'templates/partialCustomHeader.html'"></div>
     <div ui-view="second"></div>
   </ion-content>
```

And here is the map view which is very simple:

```html
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="false" class="myPageHasHeader animationLeft">
     <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
    </ion-content>
```

The problem is when running on an Android device (I haven't tested IOS yet) I correctly load the first view in this case map. But when clicking on any of the menu options the controller activates (via logs I can tell) but the screen remains displaying the map. If I click on the final menu option the app will update visually to display the 2nd view, yet the next controller activates.

The more odd thing is when using chrome inspector it shows the views navigating just fine on the android phone. Even dragging and moving is updated appropriately.

The problem I feel is that somehow the rendering isn't be refreshed or updated, and only upon clicking on another state change item will it update to one behind it.  I have disabled all animations to ensure that isn't the problem.

EDIT: Here is a working codepen that sorta shows what i'm trying to do: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdRLag

Comment: can you post a codepen?

Comment: I edited the question with a codepen link, granted its pretty rough, but its the way i'm hoping to do it. I still feel the problem is something on Android that causes the view not to update, no luck yet though...

Comment: Seems, I am also facing with this issues on ionic latest 3.7.1. Works fine on iOS but Android.